# No live preview & SEO plugin cannot find content on page

Tags: live-preview, seo

When I try to live preview my craft site the content of the live preview is blank:

[image]

This is happening for all pages.

I have set the template file for the page to use:

[image]

I am running Craft Solo 3.6.12

Something that is also kinda odd is that the SEO plugin I am using cannot seem to detect the content on the page, my suspicion is that these two things are linked:

SEO plugin:

[image]

I get an odd error when trying to use the SEO plugin for key words:

[image]

I have looked at some of the issue on github but have not been very successful finding a solution so if anyone has come across this before and could offer some dev wisdom that would be great.

Please ask any questions you might have,
all the best - W

Comment: Could you share what's in your `templates/index` file?

Comment: Hi Oli - Have you seen this behavior before when an issue is present in the twig file? The reason I ask is that all pages are not showing in the preview and they are all different so maybe there is a common dominator in the head / header / footer

Comment: Also side note here but the Preview Targets is not diplaying at all - not sure if that is because this is a Solo craft and not pro

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple answer - the .env file was not showing the correct primary site i.e.

```
PRIMARY_SITE_URL=https://www.XXXXXXX.com

http:// XXXXXX
```

should have been

```
https:// XXXXXX
```

very embarrassingly for me, this error was clearly displayed in the console log of the live preview site i.e.

- navigate to the live preview page
- enter dev tools
- view console for the log errors

There is also another post of this issue as well:

[Live Preview not loading - https / http conflict](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30119/live-preview-not-loading-https-http-conflict)

(I'd like to suggest this post be left open as I had previously seen that post but did not attribute it to this issue - possibly due the double digits spent infront of the screen...)